# How find $\overbrace{999\dots 9}^{2^{n+2}}\over 99$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find $\overbrace{999\dots 9}^{2^{n+2}}\over 99$.
Would you help me to find out exact answer?

Comment: What about $n$? Is it $n \geq 0$?

Comment: Try some induction. It seems to be $$\;\overbrace{101010....101}^{2^{n+2}-1\;\text{digits}}$$

Comment: Seems like, $\dfrac{10^{2^{\large{n+2}}}-1}{99}$

Answer (score 6):

$$\underbrace{99...9}_{k\text{ -digits}}=10^{k}-1;\quad99=10^2-1$$
So you wish to seek:
$$\frac{10^{2^{n+2}}-1}{10^2-1}=\sum_{k=0}^{2^{n+1}-1}10^{2k}=\underbrace{101010...101}_{2^{n+2}-1\quad \text{digits}}$$

Answer (score 3):

Let's denote $a_n = \underbrace{999\dots 9}_{n}, b = 99$. You have to find $q$ such that $a_{n+2} = qb$. Let's note that
$$
a_n +1 = 10^{n-2}(b+1) = 10^{n-2}b + 10^{n-2}\\
\Rightarrow a_n = 10^{n-2}b + a_{n-2}
$$
Now we can use induction and say that $a_n = (10^{n-2}+10^{n-4}+\dots)b$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$\overbrace{999\dots 9}^{k}=9(1+10+10^2+...+10^k)=10^{k+1}-1.$$ Also $$\overbrace{999\dots 9}^{2^k}=99\times10^{2^k-2}+99\times10^{2^k-4}+99\times10^{2^k-6}+...+99$$